# Internal storage project

Tags: java, android

hello everyone out there. here is my project. since I am a beginner at Java programming I am trying different types of storage, right now internal storage.  I have a screen that accepts a username and password, when saved it saves a text file, david.txt . I go to the second screen push load and the information is pulled from the text file and populates the Username and Password.

this is the code for Main Activity

```
public static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

EditText userName, password;

//... standard stuff

    userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userName);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
}

public void save (View view)
{
    String text1 = userName.getText().toString(); // example: David
    String text2 = password.getText().toString(); // Example: Vilma123
    File file=null;
    text1=text1+" "; // Adds space between username and password
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream=null;

        try {
        file=getFilesDir(); //Gets directory of stored file
        fileOutputStream = openFileOutput("david", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fileOutputStream.write(text1.getBytes());
        fileOutputStream.write(text2.getBytes());

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
    }
    finally{
        try {
            fileOutputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
        }
    }



    Toast.makeText(this, "Saved successfully"+file+" /david.txt", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

this works great, on the screen it I push "Go to B" button which activates the "load" method in the SecondActivity page: see below

```
EditText userName, password;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);

}
public void load (View view)
{   
        Log.d("david", "starting fileInputStream");

        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream =      openFileInput("david.txt");
            int read = -1; //-1 indicates file is empty
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            while ((read = fileInputStream.read())!=-1);
            {
                buffer.append((char)read);
            }

                Log.d("david", buffer.toString());

                String user = buffer.substring(0, buffer.indexOf(""));

                String pass = buffer.substring(buffer.indexOf("")+1);

                userName.setText(user);
                password.setText(pass);

        fileInputStream.close();


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   


    Toast.makeText(this, "Load successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

ok this is where it get fun. when I push the Load button it is supposed to load the username and password which i typed in the last screen but it is not loading.
This log file has a 0 value

```
Log.d("david", buffer.toString());
```

but the .txt file has the info I placed.  Could some one please help me on this one.  I show no errors and all Toasts display as they should.

Comment: file is costly process, do use of preferences android has mechanism called preferences for small piece data storage

Comment: you can store username and password in shared preference in encrypted form so that no one can read it.

Comment: @sush please explain your thoughts, I am understanding what states to store in a shared preferences state and then recall.  So in conclusion have the code save the data to a determined place and  access the data using shared preferences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Preference
{

  // check for username length
   public static String getUserName(Context context)
   {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString(
            "username", "");
   }

  public static boolean setUserName(Context context,String username)
  {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context.getApplicationContext()).edit()
            .putString("username", username).commit();
  } 

// check for password length 
  public static String getPassword(Context context)
  {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context.getApplicationContext()).getString(
            "password", "");
  }


  public static boolean setPassword(Context context,String password)
  {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context.getApplicationContext()).edit()
            .putString("password", password).commit();
  } 


}
```

Comment: The question asked seeks conceptual understanding in the context of a made-up problem, not a best-practices solution for a real application.  The mechanism the poster is trying to use *should be* workable, and may be an exercise towards an eventual goal that really is better filled by a file than by preferences.

Comment: thank you @sush for your help. great idea I will implement into the project.

Comment: @chrisStratton  You are correct it is only for me to get the idea of using internal storage.  I am new to programming and I really do appreciate all the help that everyone is willing to give on this site.  Truly incredible how many people are willing to help.  :-)

Comment: @ChrisStratton yes your right, but correct way is important than showing only solution

Comment: @Sush - there is no single "correct" way.  What you have proposed is more Android-style for a small data item, but we don't know that the data will always be small.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a small mistake which is while storing data you are using file name `david` and while retriving data you are using file name `david.txt`

In MainActivity, change your following line,

```
fileOutputStream = openFileOutput("david", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

with this line,

```
fileOutputStream = openFileOutput("david.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: I edited the code per your comments, unfortunately it still does the same thing.    Log.d("david", buffer.toString()); still shows no data.   Also I have checked the david.txt file in the emulator and the contents do exist.  What else do you think it could be.  thanks for your response